# SSL for custom domain with google apps

Tags: ssl, google-apps

I follow google's tutorial to add an SSL to my custom domain.

From Google Apps, I have added my app as a service. Then, I can add an URL with the domain of my choice. But when I try, I have an error "incorrect domain".

I didn't have this error with the principal domain, but only with the second (that I have added two months before, operating for mails).

Have you an idea of where could be my error?

Comment: Are CNAMEs configured properly on your domain hosting service? Are they propagated? https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Comment: Yes I think, I can send and receive mail over him.

Comment: What's your custom domain name?

Comment: Domain name: campana.io

Comment: The DNS records seems to be ok (pointing to Google servers). So it is on the Google Apps config side. You said that you had one working already so it's unlikely that you are missing something on the config side. Where exactly do you get the error "incorrect domain"? What do you need your custom domain name for? Google Apps in general, App Engine?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I use the domain for mails and website. For the error: Since my Google Apps administration page, I go on the App Engine icon, then I see in a list my project ID, I click on, then I on a page where I can add a new URL, with two choices for me (because I have two domains of course). When I put "www" in the input, and I select the domain I want (who is not the principal domain), I get the error message "incorrect domain". Maybe in english it's not the same message... In french, it's "Domaine incorrecte".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from google support:

"Unfortunately Google Apps does not support secondary domains for your App Engine app"
"The only solution would be to use your primary domain or set up a new account"